# Simple Event example

Tags: javascript, jquery

i only know basic javascript and not even basic jquery, but i would like to know something that is probably really trivial in jquery.

I would like a very simple example of how to create a function in a js file and execute that with a dom class parameter(like .sample) from my main script. Something like :

```
$('.sample').execute(200);
```

How would you go about writing this type of function in the jquery js file ? Simply put, i want an example to better understand how $() is used with jquery methods and how .sample is passed as a parameter to execute() and how it's used in it.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to know how to do that in plain JS first so that you know what is actually happening? And whether jQuery is helping or hindering?

Comment: thanx about the polite RTFD. The problem is that i couldn't actually find that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly you are basically asking how to write a jQuery plugin.

The basic idea is this:

```
(function($) {
    //$.fn is an alias for $.prototype
    $.fn.execute = function(someParam) {
        //"this" refers to jQuery object on which method has been called
    };
})(jQuery); //Pass jQuery to anonymous function so we don't overwrite $
```

This can then be called as you showed in your question:

```
$("someSelector").execute(whatever);
```

You can learn alot more on the [jQuery Plugin Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) page. If you want to actually understand what the above code means, and what actually happens, it's probably worth getting to grips with JavaScript before looking at jQuery.

Comment: yes, this is actually what i wanted. It's not that i don't know js at all,i understand it and can write, but i'm no expert for sure.